# PHPExcel setVisible(false) doesnt work

Tags: symfony, phpexcel, visible

I convert my Excel files existing in my hard disk to HTML table.
My "showAction" works great ! using **PHPExcel 1.8**, **symfony 2.5** & **PHP 5.3.13**

I just want only the first 14 column displaying.
I've to do a Filter.

My `ReadFilter` class :

```
class MyReadFilter implements PHPExcel_Reader_IReadFilter {

    public function __construct($fromColumn, $toColumn) {
        $this->columns = array();
        $toColumn++;
        while ($fromColumn !== $toColumn) {
            $this->columns[] = $fromColumn++;
        }
    }

    public function readCell($column, $row, $worksheetName = '') {
          if (in_array($column, $this->columns)) {
              return true;
          }
          return false;
      }
}
```

My `showAction()` function in my DefaultController :

```
public function showAction()
{
    $ami = glob('path/to/directory.{xlsx,xls,xlsm,xlsm.ink}', GLOB_BRACE);

    $filterSubset = new MyReadFilter('A', 'N'); 

    $objReader = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReaderForFile($ami[0]);

    $objReader->setReadFilter($filterSubset); 

    $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($ami[0]);

    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

    $writer = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, "HTML");

    $writer->generateStyles();
    $writer->generateSheetData();

    return $this->render('MyBundle:Default:testexcel.html.twig', array(
        'excelHtml'=>$writer,
        'stylesExcel'=>$writer,
    ));
}
```

The problem is, blanks columns('O','P','Q')

```
<td class="column14">&nbsp;</td>

<td class="column15">&nbsp;</td>
```

still dispaying..
Is there a way to fully hide them ?

[HTML table result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aT7HT.png)

Thanks a lot ! @Mark Baker

Comment: OK, what browser are you using? When rendering HTML, PHPExcel uses style settings of `visibility="collapse"` and `*display="none"` to try and hide columns, but not all browsers support these style options

Comment: I'm using google chrome sir

Comment: On Firefox : `$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension($name)->setVisible(FALSE)->setAutoSize(true);` works but let a blank column.. `$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension($name)->setVisible(FALSE);` doesnt work.. On GoogleChrome , only removeColumn() works and let a blank column.. Do you think i have to use MyReadFilter to only show 14 columns

Comment: This is why I originally recommended that you apply a read filter to ensure that you only loaded the columns that you wanted, rather than trying to hide them in a browser

Comment: Ok i will try the read filter but i dont get it ! Thanks a lot Mark

Comment: `$column` is a letter ('A', 'B', 'C', etc) so create a property with a value like range('A','O'), then check if $column is in that range

Comment: Thanks again ! i've edited my post because blanks columns still here..

Comment: @MarkBaker Can you show me the ReadFilter function that i need to show column range('A','N') please ?